# Artifactory search API is returning empty list in case of virtual or remote repositories

Tags: artifactory

I tried searching a remote and a virtual repository in artifactory, and it is returning empty list, even though the artifacts are present in the repository.

My rest API looks like this:
https://artifactory_url/artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=*.*&repos=repo-name

When searching for artifacts in local repository, it is returning proper results.

For virtual repository, the following property : Can Retrieve Remote Artifacts : true

For remote repository, the following property : List Remote Folder Items : true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Artifactory search API is limited to searching artifacts which are physically stored in Artifactory:

1. Artifacts stored in local repositories
2. Cached artifacts stored in remote repositories - artifacts which were pulled from an external repository and are now cached within Artifactory

Artifactory does not have the ability to propagate the search queries to the external repositories (with the exception of a remote Maven repository proxying JCenter). The is an open [feature request](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-12022) to support this in the JFrog Jira.